# How to bind ajax combobox using ajax in C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, combobox

I want to bind the AJAX combobox using ASP.Net with C#. The whole thing is going perfectly but when the combobox bind in AJAX method at that time only select text is showing.

Here is my code:

```html
<asp:ComboBox ID="cmbobx_search" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" MaxLength="50" Width="251px"></asp:ComboBox>
```

```csharp
[WebMethod]
public static List<ListItem> GetComboboxYear()
{
    string query = "SELECT yearId, year FROM tbl_yearregistration";
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            List<ListItem> customers = new List<ListItem>();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(new ListItem
                    {
                        Value = sdr["yearId"].ToString(),
                        Text = sdr["year"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            return customers;
        }
    }
}
```

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yearregistration.aspx/GetComboboxYear",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (r) {
        alert("Bind Successfully...!!!");
        var ddlYear = $("[id*=cmbobx_search]");
        ddlYear.empty().append('<option selected="SELECT" value="0">SELECT</option>');
        $.each(r.d, function () {
            ddlYear.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what's `r.d`? it's seems like you's missing `function (r)` this in `success` callback

Comment: sorry typing mistake

Comment: what you get in `response` ?

Comment: only alert is coming after that only select text is coming........

Comment: why don't you `console.log(r.d)` and check what's it fetching from `webmethod`?